# Regex to check that a character in range doesn't repeat

Tags: regex, string

I want to match against Strings such as `AhKs` & `AdKs` (i.e. two cards Ah = Ace of Hearts). I want to match two off-suit cards with a regex, what I currently have is `"^[AKQJT2-9][hscd]{2}$"`, but this could match hands such as `AhKh` (suited) and `AhAh`. Is there a way to possibly use backreferences to say the second `[hscd]` cannot be the same as the firs (similarly for `[AKQJT2-9]`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
^[AKQJT2-9]([hscd])[AKQJT2-9](?!\1)[hscd]$
```

Here a [negative look-ahead assertion `(?!…)`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) is used to disallow the fourth character to be the same as the second (match of first grouping).

But if the regular expression implementation does not support look-around assertions, you will probably need to expand it to this:

```
^[AKQJT2-9](h[AKQJT2-9][scd]|s[AKQJT2-9][hcd]|c[AKQJT2-9][hsd]|d[AKQJT2-9][hsc])$
```

Answer (score 5):

Not perfectly elegant, but works:

```
^[AKQJT2-9]([hscd])[AKQJT2-9](?!\1)[hscd]$
```

Comment: +1 that's very elegant actually. My version was going to be much uglier. :)

Answer (score 1):

a negative lookahead comes to the rescue

```
/^[AKQJT2-9]([hscd])[AKQJT2-9](?!\1)[hscd]$/
```

:( too late.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Use back-reference together with a negative look-ahead.

```
^([AKQJT2-9])([hscd])(?!\1)(?!.\2)[AKQJT2-9][hscd]$
```